# Stop the swiper on mouseover and start playback on mouseout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, swiper.js

The swiper flips through the slides when you click on the buttons and works autoplay, but does not stop when the mouse cursor is over a particular swiper. What could be a mistake?

P.S. Swiper with github.
https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper/blob/master/demos/280-autoplay.html

```
<div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
  </div>

var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
      spaceBetween: 30,
      centeredSlides: true,
      autoplay: {
        delay: 2500,
        disableOnInteraction: false,
      },
      pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
        clickable: true,
      },
      navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
      },
    });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `swiper.autoplay.stop()` to pause the autoplay on `mouseover`
and `swiper.autoplay.start()` on `mouseout` to start the autoplay again.

Check the code snippet, made based on the link you provided.

```js
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
  spaceBetween: 30,
  centeredSlides: true,
  autoplay: {
    delay: 2500,
    disableOnInteraction: false,
  },
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
    clickable: true,
  },
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },
});

// now add mouseover and mouse out events on '.swiper-slide' elemnts to pause and resume the autoplay;

$('.swiper-slide').on('mouseover', function() {
  swiper.autoplay.stop();
});

$('.swiper-slide').on('mouseout', function() {
  swiper.autoplay.start();
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #eee;
  font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.swiper-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.swiper-slide {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #fff;
  /* Center slide text vertically */
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.4.1/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.4.1/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="swiper-container">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
  </div>
  <!-- Add Pagination -->
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
  <!-- Add Arrows -->
  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
</div>
```